# How can I import hbase in python?

Tags: python, hbase, cloudera

I'm trying to play around with hbase in python and I am using the cloudera repository to install the hadoop/hbase packages.  It seems to work as I can access and work on the database using the shell but its not fully working within python.

I know to communicate with hbase I need thrift so I downloaded and complied it from source, I can import thrift into python but when I do `from hbase import Hbase`, I get module not found errors.

Does anyone know what package/module I would need to get it to work? I tried to look around easy_install and yum(I'm using centos6) and no luck.  I did find an article where a person using debain installed it by doing `sudo aptiutde install python-hbase`  I don't have that command/package, so I'm not sure how to get it(or if I have to compile from source to get it).

Also if it helps, I installed most of the base from cloudera and followed some instructions(the ones didn't require install) from http://yannramin.com/2008/07/19/using-facebook-thrift-with-python-and-hbase/

Any help/tips/suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: fyi..the article I was using was almost 4 years old.  I couldn't find anything newer dealing with python but if this method is outdated than let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  If anyone else is having problems with this in the future its actually pretty easy.  In the step where you run `thrift --gen py Hbase.thrift`, it creates a hbase folder in the location you ran that command.  Simply take that command and copy it to your default module folder(or in the folder where you run your program and it should work).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at HappyBase (see https://github.com/wbolster/happybase for info). It is the modern way to interact with HBase from Python. It covers the complete Thrift API but wraps it in a much better interface.

Answer (score 0):

1. search for /src/contrib/thriftfs/gen-py under hadoop installation folder
2. Copy the output of thrift --gen py Hbase.thrif onto the location below (part till /home/hadoop/data/ will differ in your case) /home/hadoop/data/hadoop-1.0.4/src/contrib/thriftfs/gen-py

then

```
$ python
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/hadoop/data/hadoop-1.0.4/src/contrib/thriftfs/gen-py")
import hbase
```

It should work now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)